# How can I split a string with a number at the end?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with a number at the end, separated from the rest of the string by a space, e.g. two examples:

```
blah 45 blah 89

1. blah blah  blah blah  42
```

How can I use regex in Python to separate the string into the last number and the rest of the string? Thanks!

Comment: What would be the output for `blah 45 blah 89`?

Comment: Is the number always at the end of the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
In [100]: s = 'blah 45 blah 89'

In [101]: s1, n = s.rsplit(None, 1)

In [102]: s1, n
Out[102]: ('blah 45 blah', '89')
```

Comment: thanks. how can I change the code if I would like to split the string according to the first space, e.g. `blah` and `45 blah 89`?

Comment: @Tim Use `split` instead of `rsplit`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string with a number at the end and just want this number then you can use [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to partition from the right-hand side of the string.

```
a = '1. blah blah  blah blah 42'

b = a.rpartition(' ')

print(b)
# ('1. blah blah  blah blah', ' ', '42')

print(b[-1])
# '42'
```

Comment: what about the rest of the string? thanks

Comment: `str.rpartition` returns a sequence of 3 elements, (first_part, separator, last_part). If you choose the -1st element you effectively choose the last and as such you get the number.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using regular expressions, then the following will do it:

```
import re

s='blah 45 blah 89'
print re.match(r'.*\s(.*)',s).group(1)
```

Comment: The following works as well: `re.split(r'\s+',s)[-1]`

Comment: thanks. can you explain `'.*\s(.*)'`? `\s` means a white space, there are several white spaces in the string, so why is it the last one? why is there `(...)` after `\s` not both before and after it?

Comment: The dot is any character and the asterisk will eat up as many characters as it can until it hits an \s, i.e. a space. The pars then capture anything until the end of the line, which is what you asked for.

Comment: thanks. (1) why isn't the string split as `blah` and `45 blah 89`? (2)why is `'.*\s(.*)'` not `'(.*)\s(.*)'`

Comment: (1) Because * is greedy and eats as much as it can. There is also a non greedy modifier which is written *?, which would yield the ('blah','45 blah 89') output. (2) You only need the () if you want to capture something, and you only asked for the last word of the line.

Comment: thanks. (2) I also ask for the rest of the string